Holder continuous function whose inverse is also holder continuous?
Is there a monotone-increasing $\alpha$-holder continuous function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, with $f(0)=0$ whose inverse is also holder continuous ($\alpha<1$)?
The claim is not true in general, e.g., $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ whose inverse $f^{-1}(x)= x^2$ is not holder continouus.
